# php use thread to run multiple web-service xml

Tags: php, multithreading, web-services

I have a code that send xml request to web-service and bring me back hotel information:

```
$s = new soapclient("http://www.wb-service-address.com",array('wsdl'));
$HotelInfo = new stdClass;

<HotelInfo softwareID="123" SessionId="153">
     <Hotel  ID="103" /> 
</HotelInfo>

$HotelInfo->xmlRequest = $paramsStr;
$result = $s->__call("SubmitXmlString",array($HotelInfo));
$obj_pros = get_object_vars($result);
$hotel_full_xml =  $obj_pros['SubmitXmlStringResult'];  
$hotel_full_xml = simplexml_load_string($hotel_full_xml);
```

I'm looking for example for a thread code (PHP) that create web-service request, via xml, to number of URLs at the same time (simultaneous).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, PHP can not really threading and forking. The Pecl extensions do not work here either. 
This article describes the problem very well and also gives information about solutions:
https://d-mueller.de/blog/parallel-processing-in-php/

We use the gearman solution to manage many hundret of "paralell" requests.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the reply. Does CURL can create multiple xml requests?